# Nodemailer is not working in live but locally working fine

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, smtp, nodemailer

```
function sendEmail(num, email, customerName) {
    var readHTMLFile = function (path, callback) {
        fs.readFile(path, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, html) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
                callback(err);
            }
            else {
                callback(null, html);
            }
            
        });
    };

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        secure: true,
        port: 465,

        auth: {
            user:process.env.USEREMAIL,
            pass:process.env.USERPASS
        },
    });
 
    readHTMLFile(__dirname + '/views/layouts/first.html', function (err, html) {
        var template = handlebars.compile(html);
        var replacements = {
            otp: `${num}`,
            customerName: `${customerName}`

        };
        var htmlToSend = template(replacements);
        var mailOptions = {
            from: process.env.USEREMAIL,
            to: email,
            subject: "Hello ✔",
            html: htmlToSend
        };
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, response) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log("Email sent");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

All this is working fine with my localhost:8000 but after I upload(hosted) with my cyclic.sh account, my app works and getting success message, but did not get any mail with my box. sendEmail function not working in live but working locally. what is issues of the sendEmail function

Comment: Did you defined your environment variables on cyclic.sh? note that `process.env.USEREMAIL` and `process.env.USERPASS` are probably defined on your localhost but not available in your hosting environment. Please follow this doc regarding setting you your environment variables: https://docs.cyclic.sh/concepts/env_vars#cyclic

Comment: variable add in the cyclic.sh but that also not working give me solution for this

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem and fixed it by wrapping sendmail with a promise

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, response) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error)
            } else {
                resolve("email sent")
            }
        });
})
```

Comment: i have the same problem, and this solutions not works in cyclic, the promise is not resolve, and not recieved the email.