# Connection error when using NodeMailer with Nextjs 13.4

Tags: reactjs, email, next.js, nodemailer, next.js13

I am trying to send sample mail from my email to other, it is saying

```
{"message":"Error","error":{"errno":-4039,"code":"ESOCKET","syscall":"connect","address":"40.99.34.150","port":587,"command":"CONN"}}
```

The API route handler according to 13.4 is

```
export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: "gmail",
        auth: {
            user: "<my-email>",
            pass: "<valid-password-of-the-above-email>",
        },
    });
    const data = {
        from: "<my-email>",
        to: "<other-email>",
        text: "What",
        html: "<html><body>hello</body></html>",
        subject: "hello",
    };
    try {
        await transporter.sendMail(data);
        return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK" }, { status: 200 });
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({ message: "Error", error }, { status: 500 });
    }
}
```

Update:
[image]

Referred below links but were not of much help!

- [Nodemailer Nextjs Typescript form not sending emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72807193/nodemailer-nextjs-typescript-form-not-sending-emails)
- [ETIMEDOUT connect error using nodemailer in Nodejs Openshift application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473292/etimedout-connect-error-using-nodemailer-in-nodejs-openshift-application)

Feel free to redirect me to any other package which supports typescript and nextjs

Comment: can you try `transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){ if (error) { console.log(error); } });`  to see the error in detail

Comment: Hi @buga, I tried console log, but was not of much help, I couldn't see any further things in it

Comment: perhaps you need to wrap `sendMail` with promise since its uses a callback https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75158156/nodemailer-is-not-working-in-live-but-locally-working-fine/75221037?noredirect=1#comment135341922_75221037